# Pass Bearer Token on GET Request on EITHER Google Chrome / Safari / FireFox / Etc

Tags: security, authentication, browser, postman

I wanna know how I can pass a Bearer Token I got from Postman on a GET HTTP Request made on EITHER Google Chrome, Safari, FireFox, or any other browser